# Unity/C# plays Audioclip when loading scene which I dont want

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I have something like this

[image]

My SoundManager Script
[image]

My sound script
[image]

If this he
[image]

The C# Script
[image]

So I have two Audioclips I want to play in the game.
the "boing2" sound when the player hits an obstacle - this works fine.

When the player hits the goal the "JinglDingl" should play. This works fine too.

Problem is, that when the player hits the goal in the game the "boing2" plays as well. And I have no idea why.

I tried to test it with disabling both FindObjectOfType().Play(...) lines - and the game still plays the "boing2" sound when hitting the goal.

If I disable the "NextLevel" line there is no "boing2" as it is intended to be.

So my conclusion is, that unity plays the sound whenever it is loading the new scene. I have searched the editor if I ticked something wrong, but my search was not successfull.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code to your question, and show us the screenshots of the inspector of gameobjects with audio sources.  There is no way to give you an actual answer without knowing how you have your project set up.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck Play on Awake in the Audio Source.

[image: Play on Awake]

Or you can set it to false on the AudioSource in code if you create it in code

```
void Awake(){

...


    foreach(sound s in sounds) {

        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;
        s.source.playOnAwake = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hmmm, First Thank You!

Comment: Where do I find this Audiosource?

Comment: Should be on the object or prefab that plays the sound.

Comment: Well this would be my Audiomanager- I edited a screenshot in the original post. The Inspector shows nothing more

Comment: Make sure you set PlayOnAwake to false in script if you are constructing one.  The default is true.

Comment: You should also put your code in the quesiton as text instead of with screenshots ;)

Comment: Now I have something like this: [HideInInspector]
    public bool playOnAwake = false;  .... but the sound is still playing?!

Comment: Your Sound class has an AudioSource.  How is it set?   Somewhere you need source.playOnAwake = false;

Comment: public class Sound {

    public string name;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool playOnAwake = false;
    
    public AudioClip clip;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;
} .... This is my Sound Class -> playOnAwake is clearly set to false. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I mean something else.  I mean your `public AudioSource source;`

Comment: You should really edit your question as text instead of screenshots so I can cut and paste it...

Comment: source.PlayOnAwake causes a Syntax Error... Whiche is the correct Syntax to set this to false? My public AudioSource source is in the Sound Class.

Comment: Ahhh didnt see your picture at first. In theory this should work - sounds legit (pun intended). So I have tried that, but he still plays the sound upon loading a scene no matter what.

Comment: I disabled all my AudioScripts for now and he still plays the sound... So I guess there has to be somewhere I reference I may have accidentally created.